# How do I update the specific properties in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have been trying to update specific properties in EF Core. But I'm still getting an exception.

I have tried to set the state to detach but I'm getting the same exception.

```
public async Task  UpdateSpecificAsync(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] updatedProperties)
{
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    if (updatedProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
        {
            _context.Entry(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;
        }
    }
          
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Usage:

```
await _efUserRepository.UpdateSpecificAsync(userEntity, 
                x => x.Address, x => x.FirstName, x => x.LanguageId, x => x.LastName, x => x.MiddleName);
```

Exception:

> The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

**Solved With**

```
 public async Task UpdateSpecificAsync(TEntity entity, params string[] updatedProperties)
        {

            var dbentity = Entities.First(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
            foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
            {
                var newValue = entity.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(entity, null);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = dbentity.GetType().GetProperty(property);
                Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                object safeValue = (newValue == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(newValue, t);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(dbentity, safeValue, null);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }


await _efUserRepository.UpdateSpecificAsync(userModel,
                nameof(User.Address), nameof(User.FirstName), nameof(User.LanguageId), nameof(User.LanguageId), nameof(User.MiddleName));
```

I'm not really happy with it but it does solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to search in SO for such exception? I have made a lot of solutions.  Problem here that ChangeTracker already has Entity with this key and you cannot attach duplicate.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  Yes, I did the result suggests I need to detach the entity so that it won't track. I tried that as well.

Comment: Why not just update some of the properties of the tracked entity and save it?

Comment: Where did the userEntity come from?

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you'll see that `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` puts the entity *instance* in change tracker and marks *all*  properties as modified. Hence all the code after that makes no sense.

Comment: @MehdiSaeedifar It comes from a Controller. user will update it.

Comment: @lvan I tried without Modified. it didn't work. after checking in google to not track we can Modify or detach. I have tried those solutions. if it's wrong can you please suggest something? I will try to fix

Comment: @Theone, your entities has base class/interface with Id?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes it has base class with Id as Primary key

Comment: Use not `First` but `Find`

Comment: ok, thanks I will do that.

Comment: You only missed [`entry.CurrentValues.SetValues()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution#query-then-apply-changes).

Answer (score 1):

in EF7 don't need to attach the entity !
just set changed properties to to IsModified = true;

```
public void UpdateSpecificField(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] updatedProperties)
{
    foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
        _context.Entry(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;
}
```

for use this method can do :

```
var oldUser = await _appUow.UserRepo
            .Select(x => new GetUserDto { UserId = x.UserId, Name = x.Name })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId > 1);

        var newUser = new User
        {
            UserId = oldUser.UserId,
            Name = "newName3",
            Code = "code3"
        };

        _appUow.UserRepo.UpdateSpecificField(newUser, x => x.Name, x => x.Code);
        await _appUow.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then this command generate this tsql :

```
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[UserId], [u].[Name]
FROM [Base].[User] AS [u]
WHERE [u].[UserId] > 1
```

and

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Base].[User] SET [Code] = @p0, [Name] = @p1
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [UserId] = @p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

DbContext should know about your entity and if it is in a Detached state, you must attach the entity to DbContext.

```
 public async Task  UpdateSpecificAsync(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] updatedProperties)
            {
                if (_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached && 
                _context.Set<TEntity>().Local.All(e => e.Id != entity.Id))
                {
                    _context.Attach(entity);
                }

                if (updatedProperties.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var property in updatedProperties)
                    {
                        _context.Entry(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;
                    }
                }
          
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

Comment: `_context.Attach(entity);`  has given the same exception.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please test it.

Comment: I'm really sorry to say it is still the same. on this line `_context.Entry(entity).Property(property).IsModified = true;`