# How to update a database record only with properties that are not null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I wonder how to update database record with values that are transferred from client side.

```
public class UpdateDetailsCommand : CommandBase
{
 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 public Gender? BaseInfoGender { get; set; } = null;
 public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } = null;
 public string? BaseInfoCountry { get; set; } = null;
 public string? Education { get; set; } = null;
 public string? Specialization { get; set; } = null;
}
```

If user updates only Education field, this field will not be null. Should I write checker for each property and check for not null property and then update ?

```
if(command.Education != null)
{
 user.UserDetails.Education = command.Education;
}
```

Or maybe on the client side I should transfer all fields - existing and changed, and then just update the entire record?

What is the correct way to update records in database ?

Comment: The code you have for checking for null and updating the existing User object properties is fine.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you should transfer all the fields and just update the entire entity.  The pattern you propose is incompatible with having nullable attributes.

If you want to update a subset of the attributes, see: [How do I update the specific properties in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416501/how-do-i-update-the-specific-properties-in-ef-core)

Answer (score 1):

For web applications/APIs only pass what you trust them to change, and still validate values coming back With tracked entities on the server side, EF will only update values to the DB if they actually change, so if your viewmodel is structured in a way that everything is nullable and you only want to update values if they are set:

```
public class UpdateDetailsCommand : CommandBase
{
 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 public Gender? BaseInfoGender { get; set; } = null;
 public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } = null;
 public string? BaseInfoCountry { get; set; } = null;
 public string? Education { get; set; } = null;
 public string? Specialization { get; set; } = null;
}

// User entity

public class User 
{
 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 public Gender BaseInfoGender { get; set; } = null;
 public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } = null;
 public string BaseInfoCountry { get; set; } = null;
 public string Education { get; set; } = null;
 public string? Specialization { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Then your update without considering extra validation could be:

```
// TODO: Validate your view model coming in, are the values all allowed?
var user = _context.Users.Single(x => x.UserId == data.UserId);
user.BaseInfoGender = data.BaseInfoGender.HasValue ? data.BaseInfoGender : user.BaseInfoGender;
user.DateOfBirth = data.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? data.DateOfBirth : user.DateOfBirth;
// ...

_context.SaveChanges();
```

EF will only build an Update SQL statement if any of the values actually change and only for the values that change. Mappers can help copy values to avoid that boilerplate check everywhere an entity might be updated.

That said for things like a date of birth you will probably want to validate the value coming in to ensure it isn't a future date or something otherwise out of range. The key point is that be careful about trusting anything from the client. It could potentially be tampered with so it is always a good idea to validate anything coming in, dumping the session if anything is really out of whack like it looks like the client is changing something they have no business changing. I do not recommend passing entities and using something like:

```
_context.Update(passedInUser);
```

or

```
_context.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(passedInUser);
```

as this can easily overwrite something you don't intend to allow changing.